# Gravar um HTML - valor possivelmente perigoso Request.Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um TextAreaFor que recebe um conteúdo em Html, ao tentar gravar tenho um erro, adicionei em web.config o pages validateRequest="false"
Eu já testei o insert com texto comum e funciona, apenas com HTML não funciona

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult GravarDados(tb_conteudo dadosTabela)
    {
        string titulocategoria = dadosTabela.CONT_TITULO;
        string tituloconteudo  = dadosTabela.CONT_TITULO;
        string conteudoHtml    = dadosTabela.CONT_HTML;

        //grava a categoria do conteúdo 
        var tcategoriaConteudo = new ConteudoCategoriaAplicacao();
        tcategoriaConteudo.GravaCategoriaConteudo(titulocategoria);

        //pega o id da categoria para gravar o conteúdo
        var tBuscarcategoriaConteudo = new ConteudoCategoriaAplicacao();
        var DadosCategoria = tcategoriaConteudo.BuscaIdCategoriaConteudo();
        int IdCategoria = Convert.ToInt16(DadosCategoria.COCA_PK_ID);

        //grava o conteúdo 
        var tConteudo = new ConteudoAplicacao();
        tConteudo.GravaConteudo(tituloconteudo, conteudoHtml, IdCategoria);

        return  RedirectToAction("index");
    }
```

erro:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar a anotação **`[AllowHtml]`** na propriedade de `tb_conteudo` que está recebendo o conteúdo em HTML.

Exemplo:

```
public class tb_conteudo
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string CONT_HTML { get; set; }

    /* Outras propriedades */
}
```

Comment: agradeço a ajuda mais não tem muito certo, tive o mesmo erro

Comment: Colocou em todos os lugares que recebem um HTML? Deu rebuild no projeto pra testar?

Comment: Fiz o teste e deu certo para um Html pequeno, se tenho ele um pouco maior tenho erro. por causa do tamanho? não tenho uma ideia, mais funcionou para um pequeno

Comment: Sim, aí o problema é completamente outro. Tem a ver com o tamanho da requisição recebida.

Comment: Deu certo, testei novamente e tudo funciona